# Set parent controller property from child controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a `flyers` route that has a template called `flyers.hbs`

```
<div class="button-wrap">
    <button {{action 'back'}}>Go Back</button>
    {{#if isPrintable}}
        <button {{action 'print'}} class="float-right">Print Flyer</button>
    {{/if}}
</div>

{{outlet}}
```

In this `flyers` route I have `view` and `new`. `New` should only show the back button and `view` should show the back button and the print button.
So in the `view` controller I specified a property like so.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    isPrintable: true,
});
```

But obviously the parent controller for `flyers` does not see that property when I navigate to the `view` route so my print button is not showing.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you do not need nesting here. You could simply use query parameter `isPrintable`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I understand you'd like to have `{{isPrintable}}` in `flyers` template with value dependent of active child route.
Maybe this will work for you.

```
//flyers controller
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   isPrintable: true,
});

//child route
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  parentController: Ember.computed( function() {
    return this.controllerFor('flyers');
  }),

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    this.get('parentController').set('isPrintable', false);
  },

  deactivate: function() {
    this.get('parentController').set('isPrintable', true);
  }
});
```